# Did not received mail using Java Mail API

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I want to write a program which can send mail. I created a VM and installed Windows Server 2012 in it and configured it's SMTP Server. Now when I am trying to send email through my program, I am not getting any exception, also I am not receiving the mail. I found that the mail I sent was received by the SMTP server and it was in it's mailroot/Queue Folder. Following is the code.

```
    String to = "shreyaskothari@gmail.com";
    String from = "shreyaskothari@gmail.com";
    String host = "// VM IP Address";

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");


    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);


    try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject("First Email from Java");
        message.setText("Hello, This is first email from a Java Program");
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Message Sent");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have u tried to send email using telnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VM was not connected to Internet. Once VM got connected to Internet, I received the mail.